# Nuxt js with Docker: module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Tags: javascript, docker, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I have project in nuxt js which works fine without docker in my Windows OS. I tried install it inside docker and run but get error with message:

```
#9 126.5 ERROR in ./pages/index.vue
#9 126.5 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './main/index.js?vue&type=script&lang=js&' in '/web/pages'
#9 126.5  @ ./pages/index.vue 2:0-61 3:0-56 3:0-56 10:2-8
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/router.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/index.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5  @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5
#9 126.5 ERROR in ./pages/index.vue
#9 126.5 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/web'
#9 126.5  @ ./pages/index.vue 4:0-93
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/router.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/index.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5  @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5
#9 126.5 ERROR in ./components/shared/Button/Button.vue
#9 126.5 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/web'
#9 126.5  @ ./components/shared/Button/Button.vue 4:0-70
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/components/plugin.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/index.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5  @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5
#9 126.5 ERROR in ./components/shared/Social/Social.vue
#9 126.5 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/web'
#9 126.5  @ ./components/shared/Social/Social.vue 4:0-70
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/components/plugin.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/index.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5  @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5
#9 126.5 ERROR in ./components/shared/Item/Item.vue
#9 126.5 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/web'
#9 126.5  @ ./components/shared/Item/Item.vue 4:0-92
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/components/plugin.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/index.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5  @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5
#9 126.5 ERROR in ./components/partials/SideNav/SideNav.vue
#9 126.5 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/web'
#9 126.5  @ ./components/partials/SideNav/SideNav.vue 3:0-95
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/components/plugin.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/index.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5  @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5
#9 126.5 ERROR in ./components/partials/GroupItem/GroupItem.vue
#9 126.5 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/web'
#9 126.5  @ ./components/partials/GroupItem/GroupItem.vue 4:0-97
#9 126.5  @ ./pages/index.vue
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/router.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/index.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5  @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5
#9 126.5 ERROR in ./components/partials/Info/Info.vue
#9 126.5 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/web'
#9 126.5  @ ./components/partials/Info/Info.vue 4:0-68
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/components/plugin.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/index.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5  @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5
#9 126.5 ERROR in ./components/partials/Banner/Banner.vue
#9 126.5 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/web'
#9 126.5  @ ./components/partials/Banner/Banner.vue 4:0-94
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/components/plugin.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/index.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5  @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5
#9 126.5 ERROR in ./pages/invest/invest.vue
#9 126.5 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/web'
#9 126.5  @ ./pages/invest/invest.vue 4:0-94
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/router.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/index.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5  @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5
#9 126.5 ERROR in ./pages/about/index.vue
#9 126.5 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/web'
#9 126.5  @ ./pages/about/index.vue 4:0-93
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/router.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/index.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5  @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5
#9 126.5 ERROR in ./components/elements/Side/Side.vue
#9 126.5 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/web'
#9 126.5  @ ./components/elements/Side/Side.vue 4:0-92
#9 126.5  @ ./layouts/default.vue
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/App.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/index.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5  @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5
#9 126.5 ERROR in ./components/elements/Header/Header.vue
#9 126.5 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/web'
#9 126.5  @ ./components/elements/Header/Header.vue 4:0-94
#9 126.5  @ ./layouts/default.vue
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/App.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/index.js
#9 126.5  @ ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5  @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./.nuxt/client.js
#9 126.5
#9 126.5  FATAL  Nuxt build error
#9 126.5
#9 126.5   at WebpackBundler.webpackCompile (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:2127:21)
#9 126.5   at async WebpackBundler.build (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:2076:5)
#9 126.5   at async Builder.build (node_modules/@nuxt/builder/dist/builder.js:327:5)
#9 126.5   at async Object.run (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-build.js:110:7)
#9 126.5   at async NuxtCommand.run (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-index.js:413:7)
#9 126.5
#9 126.5
#9 126.5    ╭─────────────────────────────╮
#9 126.5    │                             │
#9 126.5    │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error        │
#9 126.5    │                             │
#9 126.5    │   Error: Nuxt build error   │
#9 126.5    │                             │
#9 126.5    ╰─────────────────────────────╯
#9 126.5
#9 126.5 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
#9 126.5 npm ERR! errno 1
#9 126.5 npm ERR! pp@1.0.0 build: `nuxt build`
#9 126.5 npm ERR! Exit status 1
#9 126.5 npm ERR!
#9 126.5 npm ERR! Failed at the pp@1.0.0 build script.
#9 126.5 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
#9 126.6
#9 126.6 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#9 126.6 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-30T04_35_12_443Z-debug.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk update && apk upgrade && apk add git python3  &&        rm -rf node_modules &&       rm -rf .nuxt &&         node -v &&      npm install &&  npm audit fix &&    npm run build]: exit code: 1
```

Here you can see my project `pages` folder tree view:

[image]

Nuxt **config** file code:

```
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

export default {
    ssr: true,
    target: 'server', // server or static
    ...(!isDev && { modern: 'server' }),
    head: {
        title: 'Website',
        htmlAttrs: {
            lang: 'en'
        },
        meta: [
            { charset: 'utf-8' },
            { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
            { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Website' }
        ],
        link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }]
    },
    loadingIndicator: {
        name: 'pulse',
        color: '#3B8070',
        background: '#192559'
    },
    css: [
        '@/assets/css/main'
    ],
    styleResources: {
        
    },
    components: {
        dirs: ['@/components', '@/components/elements', '@/components/partials', '@/components/shared']
    },

    buildModules: [
        '@nuxtjs/stylelint-module',
        '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
        '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
        '@nuxtjs/svg',
        '@nuxt/image',
        '@nuxtjs/google-fonts'
    ],

    modules: [
        ['@nuxtjs/component-cache', { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 15 }],
        'nuxt-ssr-cache',
        '@nuxtjs/axios'
    ],
    image: {
        imgix: {
            baseURL: 'https://assets.imgix.net'
        },
        screens: {
            sm: 568,
            md: 768,
            lg: 1024,
            xl: 1280,
            xxl: 1536
        }
    },
    cache: {
        store: {
            max: 100,
            ttl: 5,
            type: 'multi',
            stores: [{ type: 'memory' /* ... */ }, { type: 'redis' /* ... */ }]
        }
    },
    googleFonts: {
        prefetch: true,
        preconnect: true,
        preload: true,
        families: {
            Manrope: [300, 400, 700, 800]
        },
        display: 'swap'
    },

    router: {
        prefetchLinks: false
    },
    tailwindcss: {
        configPath: '~tailwind.config.js',
        cssPath: '~/assets/css/tailwind.css',
        jit: true, 
        exposeConfig: false 
    },
    // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
    build: {
        extractCSS: true,
        compressor: true,
        filenames: {
            app: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[name].js' : 'js/[name]-[contenthash].js'),
            chunk: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[name].js' : 'js/[contenthash].js'),
            css: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[name].css' : 'css/[name]-[contenthash:7].css'),
            img: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : 'img/[contenthash:7].[ext]'),
            font: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : 'fonts/[contenthash:7].[ext]'),
            video: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : 'videos/[contenthash:7].[ext]')
        },
        postcss: {
            ...(!isDev && {
                preset: {
                    browsers: 'last 2 versions',
                    autoprefixer: true,
                    grid: true
                }
            })
        },

        optimization: {
            minimize: !isDev
            // runtimeChunk: true
        },
        ...(!isDev && {
            splitChunks: {
                chunks: 'all',
                layouts: true,
                pages: true,
                commons: true,
                automaticNameDelimiter: '.',
                name: true,
                maxInitialRequests: Infinity
            }
        }),
        extend(config, ctx) {
            if (config.resolve.extensions) {
                config.resolve.extensions.push(['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css'])
            } else {
                config.resolve.extensions = ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
            }
            config.resolve.modulesDirectories = ['node_modules']

            // Run ESLint on save
            if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
                config.module.rules.push({
                    enforce: 'pre',
                    test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
                    loader: 'eslint-loader',
                    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                    options: {
                        fix: true
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My project `package.json` file code:

```
{
    "name": "we",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "nuxt",
        "build": "nuxt build",
        "start": "nuxt start",
        "go": "nuxt build && nuxt start",
        "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
        "lint": "npm run lint:js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@nuxt/image": "^0.4.1",
        "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.1",
        "@nuxtjs/component-cache": "^1.1.6",
        "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.0.0",
        "@nuxtjs/stylelint-module": "^4.0.0",
        "@nuxtjs/svg": "^0.1.12",
        "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.0.1",
        "core-js": "^3.9.1",
        "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
        "nuxt": "^2.15.3",
        "nuxt-ssr-cache": "^1.5.2",
        "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
        "swiper": "^5.4.5",
        "vue-awesome-swiper": "^4.1.1",
        "vue-lazy-hydration": "^2.0.0-beta.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@nuxt/postcss8": "^1.1.3",
        "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^6.0.0",
        "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
        "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^1.3.0",
        "@tailwindcss/jit": "^0.1.15",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^7.22.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
        "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.7.0",
        "nuxt-vite": "^0.0.36",
        "postcss": "^7.0.32",
        "prettier": "^2.2.1",
        "sass": "^1.32.8",
        "stylelint": "^13.13.0",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "^21.0.0"
    }
}
```

**Node version:** v12.18.3

My `index.vue` file from where come errors:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Hello World></h2>
  </div>
</template>
<script src="./about.js" />
<style lang="postcss" scoped>
@import './css/History.css';
@import './css/Mission.css';
@import './css/Strategy.css';
@import './css/Team.css';
@import './css/Trust.css';
</style>
```

My `Dockerfile` source code:

```
FROM node:12.19.0-alpine3.12

ENV APP_ROOT /web
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
ADD . ${APP_ROOT}


RUN rm -rf node_modules && \
    rm -rf .nuxt && \
    node -v && \
    npm install && npm i eslint-webpack-plugin && npm install style-loader --save \
    npm audit fix && \
    npm run build

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

**Why I get like this errors inside docker?**

Comment: any reason for using `ADD` instead of `COPY`? Also see [https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/deployment-cloud-run/](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/deployment-cloud-run/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be regarding the `style-loader` library, not recognised when running your container.

Giving a deeper look into it, I noticed you forgot the `&&` on the line where you install it (on your `dockerfile`).

Also, not sure if you have a reason for it, but I would have all dependencies listed on the `package.json` for consistency, which means I would move `eslint-webpack-plugin` and `style-loader` directly on the json so the project always run with those libraries too.